# Running a Windows .exe service on Ubuntu (with Mono?)

Tags: 16.04, services, mono, init, init.d

I have a service that was coded that I need to move over to linux. Got the code and got it up and running as a .exe on windows to start using installutil.

However quite unsure how to get it working on ubuntu. From what I researched I needed mono, so I downloaded the complete mono and transferred my files over to my linux machine. I tried to run the service with the following command: mono-service myservice.exe (I am in the same directory as it). and it just seems like it didn't do anything. No error, no message, just went to a new prompt. It did create a PID but no service.

Checked my list of services and it was not there.

Is there a way to get this .exe running on start up (or at all even). Can't find any good example of init.d for exe files if that is what is required. Perhaps I am missing an important step. Any ideas?

Note: This got posted a duplicated to how to install a process. I am not trying to do that, I am trying to run it as a service. Which to my knowledge is not the same thing.

Version is 16.04

Comment: Everyone who is voting to close this question, it is not "too broad," nor is it a duplicate of how to install windows software. C# applications can be run on both Linux and Windows depending on how they are developed. This question is specifically about how to run such an application that is designed to run as a service, on Ubuntu, similar to how it is done on Windows. It is perfectly on topic and a straight forward question.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I do not believe that is the case. I can already run the process, it has a PID when I run it, it just does not get listed as a service. Hence the question of how to list it as a service.

Comment: @DavidFoerster edited. Its 16.04

Comment: In that case you only need to create a systemd unit for your service. I couldn't find a comprehensive Q&A on Ask Ubuntu but on [Unix.SE] there's [How to write startup script for systemd?](/q/47695/47852)

Comment: @DavidFoerster You linked to a python based question? Also does it need to be on start up? I can't just run it as a service for testing purposes without that?

Comment: Oops, that should have been [How to write startup script for systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47695/47852) The unit descriptor allows you to select under which conditions a unit/service runs; I'm sure there's a setting for "manual only".

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks for your help, but I don't think this will be of help. I just have the .exe only. Here it seems like it is needed to edit the script. Also even if I could, it feels not that useful, the .service example seems very specific for graphic cards. There really is not a simple way to run a generic .exe (which can be run as a service on windows) as a service on linux? Seems like an answer to this should exist.

Comment: On Unix-like systems services are (usually) managed by the init system which defaults to systemd on Ubuntu Xenial and its successors for the forseeable future. If you want to set up a service that you can manage through the init system you'll need to write systemd units sooner or later. As often there are other options but they're either outdated/deprecated or (likely horrible) homebrew cludges and/or don't deserve the name "service". I see nothing of relevance that is specific to graphics in the linked Q&A.